# How to set a node environment variable when runnig via webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, puppeteer

I am currently setting up testing with jest/puppeteer and want to make use of the **process.env.HEADLESS** environment variable of the default config of jest-puppeteer:

```
module.exports = {
    launch: {
        dumpio: true,
        headless: process.env.HEADLESS !== 'false'
        product: 'chrome'
    },
    browserContext: 'default',
}
```

I run my page via webpack and would like to create a different run configuration that does not use headless chrome:

```
"test": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --env testvisibly --devtool source-map",
```

I understand that I need to set this environment variable in NODE, but am currently only setting environment variables in webpack. Those it seems I cannot access in the puppeteer configuration.

What do I need to do, how do I need to write my script to

- run webpack
- also have a switch **available in my configuration file** to turn headless on/off
- I want to put this switch into the package.json -> scripts

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I am using windows!

Comment: You can do it like so:
`"test": "HEADLESS=false webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --env testvisibly --devtool source-map",`

Comment: Hi sina, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I get 'HEADLESS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi Tina, did you put it inside package.json like so:
` "scripts": {
   "test": "HEADLESS=false webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --env testvisibly --devtool source-map",
  }
`

and then ran it with `npm run test` ?

Comment: unfortunately yes I did exactly that

Comment: Could you please also test this one:
`"test": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --define process.env.HEADLESS='\"false\"' --env testvisibly --devtool source-map",`

Comment: Error: Unknown option '--define'